# Is there a paper or book about countable-open game?

Tags: general-topology, infinite-games

I am studying about topological game, and I found the progression:

Point-Open(X)>> Finite-Open(X)>>Compact-Open(X).

I understand that a natural way to extend 'be finite' is 'be compact', but looking from a cardinal point of view, the sequence would be 1 (Point) >> n (Finite)>> $\omega$ (Countable).

I have not got a book that at least mentions the possibility of the countable-open game, for this reason I would like to ask if you know any book that mentions it, or books that develop some of the other games mentioned. My goal is to see if there is any relationship between countable-open game and the others already known.

Comment: I believe the finite-open game is equivalent to the point-open game, i.e., Player I has a winning strategy in the finite-open game on a space $X$ if and only if Player I has a winning strategy in the point-open game on $X$, and the same for Player II. Do you know if there is a space $X$ on which the countable-open game is not equivalent to the point-open game? (I see no reason why they should be equivalent, but I don't see an obvious counterexample either.)

Comment: Indeed, the finite-open game and the point-open game are equivalent. Currently I am in search of a proof of equivalence or a counterexample, between countable-open and open point, although for the moment I limit myself to spaces of points $G_\delta.$ ( each point is a countable intersection of open sets.)